# What does it mean thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, swift3

[image]

I got this problem when I tried to delegate scores from `GameViewController` to `ViewController`:

[image]

It works normally if I remove `bestName`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here, don't post an image of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you run your app there will be no values in `UserDefaults`.

This means that in `viewDidLoad`, the call to:

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:)
```

will return a `nil` value. But you are assigning the result to a non-optional variable.

Change the line to:

```
if let name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"bestName") {
    bestName = name
}
```

There is no problem with the call to `integer(forKey:)` because it returns `0` if there is no existing value.